# Downcasting Objects to references in java

Tags: java, downcast

I am working on an assignment and don't understand downcasting.
For example, class Reference.java and I'm in a method that passes an object in. If that object is of type (not sure if that is the right word) then create a new Reference object. This is what I have right now but it doesn't work.

```
public method(Object obj){
     if( obj instanceof Reference){
          Object obj = new Reference();
     }
}
```

Now the constructor for Reference.java needs two parameters and I also don't understand how in the world this would work when downcasting.

Comment: `Object obj = new Reference();` should probably be `Reference ref = (Reference) obj;`

Comment: You can't declare 2 variables (including parameters) with the same identifier in the same scope. You already have something called `obj` so use another name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object obj = new Reference();
```

This is an upcasting scenario.

---

If you want downcasting, then it will be,

```
Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
```

---

When it works/when it is possible,

- Suppose, you create an **Object** class instance using **Reference** class (child class reference)

```
Object obj = new Reference();
```

This is an upcasting. And you can do that,

- In this case, you can downcast without any **ClassCastException**

```
Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
```

- But when it is not clear to you, is it Cast safe or not? This time `instanceof` helps you. So the full working code should be-

```
class Reference extends Object{ //not necessary extends Object class, but for 
                                //clearification
  ...

  public static void method(Object obj){
    if(obj instanceof Reference){
      Reference ref = (Reference) obj;
    }
  }
}
```

In the main method,

```
public static void main (String [] args) {  
    Object _obj = new Reference();  
    Reference.method(_obj);  
    //downcast successfull
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this.